# How to get harddrive serial number in C or asm without wmi

Tags: c, windows, assembly, hardware-id

how to get harddrive serial number(not the volume # wich change at each reinstall of windows) in C or asm, without wmi (cause wmi required admin right).  Any clue would be helpfull cause right now i found nothing on web in C without wmi, in dayss of searching...  Thank you.
EDIT : For windows system

Comment: I think it likely that the serial number is considered confidential information, so you cannot get it without administrator privilege.

Comment: You most probably won't be able to do this without privileged instructions.

Comment: @ Harry : serial# is not on cpu anymore for that reason, so that's why there is a variable for it now, but hard drive too...? Anyway even if mac add can be fake, it still a relaible way of id-ing computer, thus non confidential. Thank for uncertain info : at least its info.                                                    @Daniel : ok thanks too

Comment: In Windows you'd have to use `DeviceIoControl` and issue IDENTIFY commands using ATA passthrough to the drive. You would require admin-level access

Comment: *cause wmi required admin right* - Are you sure about that?  Have you tried it?  Doing `wmic diskdrive get name, serialnumber` from a non-admin account worked correctly for me.  Programmatically what you're looking for is something like [this](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?545649-WinAPI-How-to-Get-Hard-Disk-Serial-Number), but opening up a physical disk like that almost certainly requires admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

Please try my open source tool, DiskId32, which also has the source code at  http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html .  I only have an Win32 version at this time.  Maybe some day I will add a Win64 version.

Comment: Wow thanks : aaalmost solved my problem. But like you said on your website : "It runs under Windows 9X, Win NT, Win 2K and Win XP (Pro/Home)." and "has occasional problems on Windows XP, Windows 2003 Server and Vista" ... So it look hard to get those hd infos : bravo for your program!  Porting it to w7 would be long/hard i guess?  55% of OS are W7 now, so...(for my self i'm in the XP resistance mouvement! ;p )

Answer (score 0):

Hard drive serial number and other information about the harddrive like firmware version, etc. can only be obtained using SMART as far as I know and that requires special ioctls to the the block device node (/dev/sda or /dev/sdb) which is usually not available to a regular user.

I know there is a tool called smartctl which does exactly this:

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda
```

Similar tools exist (hdparm, lshw, etc.) as well.

As far as trying to figure it out this info without being a privileged user, it might be possible only if it is exposed via /proc or /sys which I highly doubt is being done in the current SATA block device drivers.

Comment: Im in the window$ world (wmi) for now linux-dude but thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WMI, mentioning Windows explicity in the question would have made the point clearer :)